Manganese Oxidation States, Reverse Chameleon?
A well known experiment is where a basic sodium hydroxide and sucrose solution is added to a KMnO4 solution. The colors change from purple permanganate to green manganate to yellow/orange manganese dioxide (sometimes blue hypomanganate is formed as an intermediate). This common demo is called the 'Chemical Chameleon Reaction'. After doing this, I am left with the yellow MnO2 final solution. How can I convert the yellow MnO2 back to the original purple KMnO4. I am wondering how I can do a 'Reverse Chameleon'.

I know as chameleon reaction VO2^+ (yellow) -> VO^2+ (blue) -> V^3+ (green) -> V^2+ (violet),  obtained by reduction of NH4VO3 by Zn in diluted H2SO4.

It is not practical to synthetize MnO4- back, you need strong oxidants like S2O8^2-, PbO2 or BiO3^-. It is usually done with Mn^2+ ions, not sure how well it works with MnO2. But it would be at acidic pH, so no chameleon reversal.

I actually tried it myself with hydrogen peroxide (nothing happened) so I realized h2o2 wasn't a strong enough oxidant.

And that vanadium chameleon was easily reversed by carefully dosed H2O2. // As MnO2 is the good catalyst for H2O2 decomposition, it may not be the best idea.)

oh yup, I completely forgot that mno2 would decompose h2o2 before it could oxidise the mno2, completely forgot about the 'genie in a bottle' experiment.

See also Youtube - Vanadium Oxidation States - a most colorful experiment

Probably your best approach is to use the methods reported by Wikipedia. The most commonly used method in industry involves these steps:

Dissolve solid $\ce{MnO2}$ in molten potassium hydroxide plus an oxidizing agent. Air, potassium chlorate and potassium nitrate are reported as possibilities for the oxidizer. This forms $\ce{K2MnO4}$, the green manganese(VI) compound.

Electrolyze the $\ce{K2MnO4}$ as an alkaline aqueous solution, forming $\ce{KMnO4}$ anodically. This has an advantage over a disproportionation approach of recovering all the manganese (theoretically) in the +7 oxidaton state.



thanks for the clarification :))

It is possible the OP means doing so in a wet way in the used solution.

@Poutnik It is also possible that more extreme means are needed to achieve Mn(VI) or Mn(VII). As a rule, if you don't find it widely in nature you're probably going to need some very unnatural conditions to get it.

@OscarLanzi I do not doubt this reasoning at all. It is just not very clear what the OP had in mind. By mentioned reversal, being plausible or not, I would imagine returning somehow the solution to its original state, in situ, like you could do with vanadium.
